# Disabling Google Website Optimizer in dev and test environments (but not production)

Tags: google-website-optimizer

Presently, if I have a GWO test running in my development or test environments, then I can't very well access all of the content I want (because the control script may redirect me away from the page I want to view).

Sure, I can delete cookies and try the lottery again, but in addition to skewing my test data, that's a hassle. Is there a *convenient* way to disable GWO tracking and control without disabling javascript? Perhaps a flag I could pass in as GET data?

(I'm aware that I could alter the back end to look for said flag and output or omit the GWO code as required, but that adds an unwanted requirement to the app, which the other developers aren't bound to implement.)